# Issue with Operators and Splitting a Math Expression

Tags: python

I am working on a simple calculator that can take multiple numbers. I have the rest of the code needed from an even simpler calculator I wrote.

This snippet attempts to break up the string. I am having issues with placing operators in the `oper_lib` variable
Also, can I define a function with a generic variable and call that same function on anything I need to use it on?

```
    >""" basic calc - designed to take multiple >variables            """

   from datetime import *

   now = datetime.now()

   #Intro

   print ("\n")

   print ("Welcome to BasicCalc:Unstable! \n" )

   print ("If you need HELP, type help \n")


   print (now)

   #Beginning processing intake


   ui1 = input("Please enter figure: ")


   intake_list = ui1.split(" ")

   lenth_list= len(intake_list)


   if lenth_list % 2 == 0:
       print ("invalid entry")
   else:
       print ("")

   """
   Thoughts on this/ ideas:

   - build a secondary math op list
   - add two for - in loops in quick succession
   """

   def do_math(intake_list):
       """ proforms math function from a list"""

   oper_lib = [
           "+"  ,
           "-"  ,
           "*"  ,
           "/" 
                ]  


   for i in intake_list:
       for n in i:
           if n in oper_lib:
               intake_list.insert(i-1 , " ")
               intake_list.insert(i+1 , " ")
               print(intake_list)



   print (do_math(intake_list))    
   print (intake_list)
   print (lenth_list)
```

Comment: The program requests a figure. Is this figure a number, an expression, what? I entered 22 and it spit out these three results on separate lines:  None     ['22']        1.  Any hints you can give on what you expect the output to be?

Comment: The idea is you enter a complete expression with a space in between each integer /operand. The program takes this as a string, breaks it up into a list and processes furthor and returns an answer. So if you try to run the program with say 5-5, ,  >do_math  should break this up to >['5',  '-' ,'5']

Comment: I think you're contradicting yourself.  It looks like you're trying to make it `['5', ' ', '-', ' ', '5']`.  Also, `do_math(...)` will always return None because functions return None unless you specify the `return` keyword with a corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

In math, you're iterating through the list of characters entered by the user. If the user entered '5 - 5', intake_list contains ['5', '-', '5']. So when you iterate over it, an error will occur when using the iterator variable i and it's value is '-'. Your program is trying to subtract 1 from '-' in the line:

```
intake_list.insert(i-1 , " ")
```

I would recommend doing this:)

```
ui1 = input("Please enter figure: ")

try:
    print(eval(ui1))
except:
    print("Error on input")
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help, at least in the beginning, to think a for loop goes through each item in a "set"/"array"/"list"/etc.  The proper term is that the for loop *iterates* over each value in the provided iterable.

```
for *variable* in *iterable*
    #do something

for listValue in [12, 'apple', 24]
    print listValue
```

The above will print (to console ... different from a return keyword)

```
12
apple
24
```

However

```
for listValue in '12'
    print(listValue)
```

The above will print

```
12
```

I think I understand what you're trying to do with the second loop but you're doing too much work and it will give you the incorrect result.  (A tip for yourself and your future years/decades of debugging: run the code in your head or on paper with simple inputs, such as a list with 0, 1, or 2 values and act as the program and run line by line to see what it would do.)  The most times you can iterate over a string is once.  Based on the above, neither `i` nor `n` provide any information about the index/key/"placement" in a list, which is what it seems like you're looking for in order to insert into the list.

What you want to do is grab the current "placement" and surround it with spaces on the iterable.

A simple solution may be to keep a counter (add 1 per number or operator).  That will allow you to keep track of where you need to place spaces for the current value.

Another solution may be to count the number of items in your new list and append based on that number.

Comment: Wont a second loop be able to iterate over an object in the list? I keep trying to do this to no avail. Is it "legal" to do in python?

Comment: Just any object is not an iterable.  What are you trying to achieve by iterating over a single thing?  All you're literally doing is `listValue = '12'` unless it's a number, in which case you will error out. `12 != '12'` If something is legal doesn't mean you should do it.